# PHP Date -1 Month in March

Tags: php, date

On 30 March why date -1 month  gives 1 March and not 28/29 Feb?

```
today_date_md = "2020-03-30"
$dt_upto_pre_ = $today_date_md->modify('-1 month');
echo $dt_upto_pre_->format('Y-m-d');
```

The above code gives result as :- **2020-03-01**, but am expecting as ***2020-02-29***

Comment: If what you actually want is the last day of the previous month, then you can just specify that in your modify: `->modify('last day of previous month');`

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, when you use the modify method to subtract one month from a date, it simply subtracts 30 or 31 days, depending on the length of the month. It doesn't "roll back" to the last day of the previous month, and this behavior can lead to unexpected results in some cases.

```
$today_date_md = new DateTime("2020-03-30");
$dt_upto_pre_ = clone $today_date_md;  // create a copy to avoid modifying the original date
$dt_upto_pre_->modify('last day of previous month');
echo $dt_upto_pre_->format('Y-m-d');
```

This will output 2020-02-29 as expected.